# I want to delete data from red shift table older than 10 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to delete data from red shift table older than 10 days -  is there any script to automate this process

Answer (score 3):

There is no in-built function for deleting data older than a given period.

However, you could regularly run an SQL command that deletes rows based upon the date range of a particular column. For example:

```sql
DELETE FROM table WHERE date_field < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '10 days'
```